# Passing object type to WCF Service Application in VS 2010

Tags: c#, wcf

I need to pass several different varieties of user defined types as parameters to the same method in a WCF Service Application i.e. CompositeType, CompositeType2, CompositeType3, etc.

Here's the steps to reproduce:

Step 1. Launch Visual Studio 2010.

Step 2. Create a new "WCF Service Application" project.

Step 3. Build and run the project (Debug->Start Debugging from main menu or right click on project in Solution Explorer and click Debug->Start New Instance).

```
    Results: A Web Browser will display the contents of the web folder.
```

Step 4. Add the following to the IService1.cs interface:

```
[OperationContract]
string GetDataAsObject(object value);
[OperationContract]
CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContractAsObject(object composite);
```

Step 5. Add the following to the Service1.svc.cs service:

```
public string GetDataAsObject(object value)
{
    int tmpInt = -1;
    tmpInt = (int)value;
    return string.Format("GetDataAsObject Responded You entered: {0}", tmpInt);
}

public CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContractAsObject(object composite)
{
    CompositeType tmpCompositeType;
    tmpCompositeType = (CompositeType)composite;
    if (tmpCompositeType == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("composite");
    }
    if (tmpCompositeType.BoolValue)
    {
        tmpCompositeType.StringValue += "Suffix";
    }
    return tmpCompositeType;
}
```

Step 3. Add a new "Windows Forms Application" project to the solution.

Step 4. Right click on References in the Solution Explorer and Select "Add Service Reference" then click the Discover button then click OK.

```
    Results: A Service Reference named ServiceReference1 is added to the project.
```

Step 5. Add a button to the form and in the click event add:

```
string tmpStr = string.Empty;
ServiceReference1.Service1Client tstServiceClient;
tstServiceClient = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
tmpStr = tstServiceClient.GetData(1);
tmpStr = tstServiceClient.GetDataAsObject(1);
tmpCompositeType = new ServiceReference1.CompositeType();
tmpCompositeType.BoolValue = true;
tmpCompositeType.StringValue = "Hello";
tmpStr = tstServiceClient.GetDataUsingDataContract(tmpCompositeType);
tmpStr = tstServiceClient.GetDataUsingDataContractAsObject(tmpCompositeType);
```

Step 6. Place a break point at tmpStr = tstServiceClient.GetData(1); then Run the forms app and click the button then step over the code.

```
Results: An exception occurs at
tstServiceClient.GetDataUsingDataContractAsObject(tmpCompositeType)

The exception while trying to deserialize the message: 

There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter composite.
The InnerException message was 'Error in line 1 position 302.
Element 'http://tempuri.org/:composite' contains data from a type that maps to the name 'CompositeType'.
The deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps to this name.
Consider using a DataContractResolver or add the type corresponding
to 'CompositeType' to the list of known types - for example,
by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding it to the list
of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.'.
Please see InnerException for more details.
```

Adding the KnownTypeAttribute didn't work.
I want the minimum complexity required to make it work i.e. I don't want to replace the deserializer that is being used...I just want to fix this error,
    "The deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps to this name"
so that it knows what a CompositeType is.  Is there something that I need to add to the CompositeType class?  Is there anyway to let the deserializer know about the CompositeType type?

Comment: you should try to format your question, it is hard to read. How to tell the deserializer to know about a type? It must be included in the service contract (interface and data contracts), hence in the wsdl file, so that the client(s) and service can pass data according to that schema. How dows your wsdl file look like?

Comment: You might want to review this article: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I'd like to avoid cluttering the question with information that anyone with VS2010 already has.  In order to see the wsdl or the problem...just create a new WCF Service Application, then make a copy of the GetData(int value); and rename the copy to GetDataAsObject(object value);

Comment: Also make a copy of CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite); and rename the copy to CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContractAsObject(object composite);

Comment: Apparently, I'm not allowed to edit my comments if it takes me more than 5 minutes to look something up.

Comment: I also can't enter a return character to create a new line.  So, I'll just continue with this line.  I'd like to avoid cluttering the question with information that anyone with VS2010 already has.  In order to see the wsdl or the problem...just create a new WCF Service Application, then make a copy of the GetData(int value); and rename the copy to GetDataAsObject(object value); then verify that it works i.e. you can make this call: returnString = GetData(1234); and this call: returnString = GetDataAsObject(1234); with the same results.

Comment: Also make a copy of CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite); and rename the copy to CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContractAsObject(object composite); and you will get the error that I need to find a solution for when you call returnCompositeType GetDataUsingDataContractAsObject(composite)

Comment: There's a limit on the number of characters.  So, I'll have to include the wsdl one contract at a time.

Comment: -<wsdl:operation name="GetData">

<soap:operation style="document" soapAction="DefaultWcfServiceApplication/IService1/GetData"/>


-<wsdl:input>

<soap:body use="literal"/>

</wsdl:input>


-<wsdl:output>

<soap:body use="literal"/>

</wsdl:output>

</wsdl:operation>

Comment: -<wsdl:operation name="GetDataAsObject">

<soap:operation style="document" soapAction="DefaultWcfServiceApplication/IService1/GetDataAsObject"/>


-<wsdl:input>

<soap:body use="literal"/>

</wsdl:input>


-<wsdl:output>

<soap:body use="literal"/>

</wsdl:output>

</wsdl:operation>

Comment: -<wsdl:operation name="GetDataUsingDataContract">

<soap:operation style="document" soapAction="DefaultWcfServiceApplication/IService1/GetDataUsingDataContract"/>


-<wsdl:input>

<soap:body use="literal"/>

</wsdl:input>


-<wsdl:output>

<soap:body use="literal"/>

</wsdl:output>

</wsdl:operation>

Comment: -<wsdl:operation name="GetDataUsingDataContractAsObject">

<soap:operation style="document" soapAction="DefaultWcfServiceApplication/IService1/GetDataUsingDataContractAsObject"/>


-<wsdl:input>

<soap:body use="literal"/>

</wsdl:input>


-<wsdl:output>

<soap:body use="literal"/>

</wsdl:output>

</wsdl:operation>

Comment: So, that's the contents of the wsdl.

Comment: If it's hard to read then I'll restate the problem: 

I need to pass several different varieties of user defined types as parameters to the same method in a WCF Service Application i.e. CompositeType, CompositeType2, CompositeType3, etc.  Create a new WCF Service Application to see what I am talking about.

Comment: OK...I totally rewrote the question...hopefully it is easier to follow.  I also included step-by-step instructions to reproduce what works and what doesn't work.

Comment: Shawn Zhao in the Social.MSDN.Microsoft.com forum provided the solution.  Adding the ServiceKnownTypeAttribute to the OperationContract solves this problem.  The exception message suggested adding the KnownTypeAttribute to the DataContract which did not work.  Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 3):

Shawn Zhao in the Social.MSDN.Microsoft.com forum provided the solution. Adding the ServiceKnownTypeAttribute to the OperationContract solves this problem:

```
[OperationContract]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(CompositeType))]
CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContractAsObject(object composite);
```

The exception message suggested adding the KnownTypeAttribute to the DataContract which did not work. Thanks for your comments.